# How to view the contents of PLKLinkExit and PLKExitStatus in Xcode debugger?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ionic-framework, native

Is there any way to check the contents of objects of type PLKExitStatus and PLKLinkExit in Xcode debugger?
When i try to do `NSLog`, all i see is the type getting printed again. Same case when i use `po` in the console.

[image]

I want to know the contents of `metadata` and `status`.

When tried to print object, I just see the type

[image]